# mvc 5 jquery hide or show a control or a div based on selection from a dropdown

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to show and hide a div or a control if possible using jquery. I am new to jquery and need some help. I have this dropdown

```
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TestType , null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"})
```

and this div

```
       <div class="divqs">
        <div class="form-group" >
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QuestionSet, "QuestionSet", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("QuestionSet", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QuestionSet,"" , new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

the script I wrote is

```
$(document).ready(function ({
$('.ts').change(function (){
if ($(this).val() == 'Question Set') 
{ $('.divqs').hide();} 
else 
{ $('.divqs').show();};
});
});
```

But I am getting a problem displaying the page. I get the error "jajva script runtime error: '$' is undefined". I thought it was a problem with the jquery bundle not included but when I check the bundles it is there. What could be the problem?

Comment: You have not included the Jquery script in your app.

Comment: And nowhere in the code you have shown is there an element with `class="ts"`

Comment: Sorry I posted the wrong dropdown This is the correct dropdown. @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TestType , null,new { @class = "ts"})    And I think .net mvc comes bundled with jquery. Do I need to include it in every page I use j query in? If so how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a couple of problems in your code.

In the code you have provided:

```
$(document).ready(function ({
$('.ts').change(function (){
    if ($(this).val() == 'Question Set') 
    { 
        $('.divqs').hide();} 
    else 
    {
        $('.divqs').show();};
    });
});
```

Where is the element in your HTML that has a class name `.ts`?

So, in your HTML/Razor you need to change this line:

```
@Html.DropDownList("QuestionSet", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

To:

```
@Html.DropDownList("QuestionSet", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control ts" })
```

Also, the reason why you are receiving the error

> '$' is undefined

is because you haven't referenced jQuery in your HTML, or at least you haven't referenced it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add reference to jquery library on your webpage

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to use JQuery without including it as dependency to your html. You have to include JQuery library before trying to use it.
It is best to do this from CDN:

Answer (score 0):

Your DropDown Should look like this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TestType , null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" , id="mydropdown"})
```

and in your Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function ({
$('#mydropdown').change(function (){
if ($(this).val() == 'Question Set') 
{ $('.divqs').hide();} 
else 
{ $('.divqs').show();};
});
});
```

You should always try to use unique id's for controlling element events ...

Answer (score 0):

It's working now I added this
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js")